# Any way to combine rows together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to combine rows so that my result query are same as the correct result query.

My code:

```
SELECT space_num,
       name AS employee,
       NULL AS employee2
FROM (dbo.employee
      INNER JOIN dbo.occupancy ON employee.id = occupancy.employee_id)
RIGHT JOIN dbo.space ON occupancy.space_id = space.id
UNION
SELECT space_num,
       NULL AS employee,
       name AS employee2
FROM (dbo.employee
      INNER JOIN dbo.allocation ON employee.id = allocation.employee_id)
RIGHT JOIN dbo.space ON allocation.space_id = space.id
```

My result:

[image: my result query]

Expected result:

[image: Correct result query]

Comment: It might be helpful if you post sample data from the original tables.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably

```
SELECT e.name as employee, occupiedSpace, allocatedSpace
FROM dbo.employee e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COALESCE(oNm.employee_id, aNm.employee_id) as employee_id
      , aNm.space_num as occupiedSpace 
      , oNm.space_num as allocatedSpace
    FROM
        (SELECT employee_id, rn = row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by id), s.space_num
        FROM dbo.occupancy sp
        JOIN dbo.space s
        ON sp.space_id = s.id
        ) oNm
    FULL JOIN 
        (SELECT employee_id, rn = row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by id), s.space_num
        FROM dbo.allocation sp
        JOIN dbo.space s
        ON sp.space_id = s.id
        ) aNm
    ON oNm.employee_id = aNm.employee_id and oNm.rn= aNm.rn
) t ON e.employee_id = t.employee_id
```